# How to obliterate possibility of nulls from IEnumerable resultset

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dynamics-crm-2011, c#-5.0

**How do I eliminate checking for Any / null here?**

```
    public List<Incident> GetByServiceActivity(Guid serviceActivityGuid)
    {
        var result = from s in this._xrmServiceContext.ServiceAppointmentSet
                      join i in this._xrmServiceContext.IncidentSet on s.RegardingObjectId.Id equals i.Id
                      select i;

        return result.Any() ? result.Distinct().ToList() : new List<Incident>();
    }
```

I would like to be able to return simply 1 expression like this:

```
return from s in this._xrmServiceContext.ServiceAppointmentSet
                          join i in this._xrmServiceContext.IncidentSet on s.RegardingObjectId.Id equals i.Id
                          select i;
```

**How can we return an empty implicitly, rather than having to check for .Any()?**

Comment: `Select` will always return an empty Enumerable if no result set is found. So you can just do `return (from s in xrmServiceContext.ServiceAppointmentSet
                         join i in xrmServiceContext.IncidentSet on s.RegardingObjectId.Id equals i.Id
                         select i).ToList()` Or change your method to return an `public IEnumerable<Incident> GetByServiceActivity(Guid serviceActivityGuid)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the LINQ methods that return an `IEnumerable<T>` will *ever* return a `null` value.  They'll always return a non-null `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`.  The sequence it represents may be *empty*, but it'll never be `null`.

As for handling the empty case, there's nothing to handle.  You can call `Distinct` on an empty sequence/query just as effectively as you can on a non-empty one, and you can create a list out of an empty or non-empty sequence as well with `ToList`.  You don't need to check for anything at all.

Comment: Except of course for methods like `FirstOrDefault` which return a single instance or null/zero.

Comment: can this ever be null?:


            var result = (from number in _cmContext.SrvLocationWarmLine
                          where String.Compare(number.CurrentWarmLine, startingRange, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0
                                && String.Compare(number.CurrentWarmLine, endingRange, StringComparison.Ordinal) <= 0
                          orderby number.CurrentWarmLine descending
                          select new { Number = number.CurrentWarmLine }).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @MeggieLuski Yes, as it's not returning a sequence, it's returning a single value from that sequence.